# Why only one active partition in MBR?

Tags: boot

I was reading about bootstrapping of operating systems and read in detail about usage of MBR. But wherever I referred, they mentioned that there can be only one active partition among four primary partitions. And when the code contained in the boot sector of that active partition is executed, the user is given a menu for selecting one of the operating systems (in case of multiboot).

I have following questions regarding my above description:

1. What are disadvantages of having more than one active partition in MBR?
2. And why only four primary partition? (Is it because of the limitation of size of MBR)
3. What is the use of primary partitions other than active partition?

Comment: "This partition is active" means "boot from this partition". What in the world would having *two* active partitions even mean? Boot from *both* partitions?!

Comment: @Mehrdad
Exactly,my point was that if there are two active partitions, shouldn't  user be given options to select the partition like boot loader (grub) does?

Comment: I see what you mean. I think the problem is that there is very little information that could be displayed to the user... the message would be basically *"Press 1 to boot from partition 1, 2 for partition 2, 3 for partition 3, and 4 for partition 4"*. I guess that's possible but it's not terribly helpful. There is **nothing** that the BIOS can assume about the partition itself, so it can't read the volume label (or anything like that)... it's not like GRUB at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure bootloaders like GRUB and LILO read possible boot partitions from a configuration, and don't care so much about active/inactive partitions. Well, if you want to boot DOS/Windows from LILO/GRUB, that partition might have to be active (the boot part of DOS/Windows might require it).

Comment: @JoAreBy                                                             
I do have one doubt. Does active partition contain the bootable image  of an operating system? In my opinion an active partition has some data which is executable code and that might be an operating system but mostly this partition contains code of bootloader(grub/LILO)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia has a nice article on MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#cite_note-Sedory_2003_MBR200-24) with a lot of useful links. "Only one active partition" seems to be a design choice from the early IBM/DOS bootloader, and has remained that way since. Basically they defined multiple active partitions as an error, and checked for this error at boot. It kind of makes sense because you can only boot one operating system at a time anyway, and a forced single active partition will prevent ambiguity. If I recall correctly LILO and possibly GRUB (linux bootloaders) don't mind if there are multiple active partitions, so I think this is a DOS/Windows issue mostly.

As for your questions.

1. An "active" partition only means that the first byte is different from an "inactive" partition. There's no advantage or disadvantage, it's just a flag.
2. Partition information is stored in a fixed size record, and it has only room for 4 partitons. However, "extended" and "logical" partitions (which are stored separately) can be used to enable more than 4 partitions. Only primary partitions can be used for booting.
3. DOS/Windows has no particular use of more than a single partition, but a user can decide to partition his disk for convenience. A partition is a logical volume that shows up as drive letter and "disk" in "My Computer". One advantage of having a partition separate from the operating system is that you store files there and later reinstall the operating system without loosing all your files. Installing an operating system usually involves formatting (erasing) a partition.

   Linux (or rather Un*x) has a tradition of using partitions to improve system resillience, by keeping essential tools and boot images on a single small partition. That way the essential parts of the system are less likely to suffer from disk errors. This can be done more elaborately by segmenting different parts of the system into different partitions with the intention of isolating any disk error that might occur. A major advantage of this is that you can use the essential system to recover from many errors that otherwise would be impossible to recover from.